# Using image-rendering: pixelated; causes moving image to ripple a vertical pixel line

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I'm attempting to create a simple javascript canvas game in a desktop app using an electron. I'm using pixel art, so in order to keep my pixel art images to stay in good quality as they scale, I am using the following CSS:

```
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

Unfortunately, as the player controls the main sprite to make it move left and right, a strange ripple effect shifts a line through the sprite as it moves.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cFp5.jpg

If I only use crisp-edges, this problem is fixed, but obviously a lot of quality is lost from the art.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this effect and just keep each pixel in its correct place?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this line of JavaScript, you should be able to remove all of that CSS. This will disable the smooth upscaling of images and keep the pixelated quality.

Replace `context` with your 2D canvas context.

```js
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Doing this was similar to only using only `image-rendering: crisp-edges` in css. Still is slightly blurry, and not as crisp as using `mage-rendering: pixelated`

Comment: @HappyDragon you could try rounding the positions and sizes of your images. Also, your canvas might be being upscaled if you are setting the width and height through the CSS.